# Global property for DB access rather than passing DB around everywhere? Advice anyone?

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, properties, global-variables

Globals are evil right? At least everything I read says so, because something might alter the state of the global at any point.

However, I've a DB object that's a bit of a tramp in regards class parameters. The property below is an instance of a wrapper class that automatically works in MS Access or SQL - hence why it's not EF or some other ORM.

```
Public Property db As New DBI.DBI(DBI.DBI.modeenum.access, String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0} ;Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=""lkjhgfds8928""", GetRpcd("c:\cms")))
```

The code itself does have PostSharp for exception handling, so I'm thinking that I can conditionally handle oledb errors by logging them and re initialising the DB if it is Null.

Up till now, the solution has been to continually pass the db around as a parameter to every single class that needs it. Most of the data classes have a shared observablecollection that is built from structures that individually implement inotifyproperty changed. One of these is asynchronously built. The collection property checks if it's empty before firing off the private Async buildCollection sub.

Given that we don't use dependency injection (yet) as I need to learn it; is the Global property all that bad? Db is needed everywhere that data is pulled in or saved. The only places I don't need it at all is the View and its code behind.

It's not a customer facing project but it does need to be solid.

Any advice gratefully recieved!!

Comment: I usually just keep the connection string as a global value/setting. Then create new db objects whenever I need them. Open, Query, Close and dispose everytime to avoid issues. Is this not an option for you?

Comment: @WozzeC Not so easily as I'm using the wrapper db class, I need an instance wherever I go in the data layer. My alternatives seem to be a global object, an additional parameter on each data class, or a creation of said instance in each class. Technically I guess the latter is better practice, combined with the global resource you suggest as at least I avoid the tramp parameter or global evil. I just am uncertain if that's the option. What do others do when they have to handle ms access? The wrapper is mandatory at this time.

Comment: The access file changes with version number, hence the discovery function which does complicate a simple global connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing the DB connection as a parameter into your classes IS using dependency injection, perhaps you just didn't recognize it as such.  Hard coding the connection string in the callers is still code that is not free of dependencies, but at least your database accessors themselves are free of the dependency upon a global connection.

Globals aren't just evil because they change without notice - that's just one effect you see resulting from the bad design choice.  They're evil because a design using them is brittle.  Code that depends upon globals requires invisible stuff to be set correctly before calling it, and that leads to inter-dependencies between unrelated code.  The invisible stuff becomes critically important stuff.  Reading just the interface of a module that internally uses globals, how would I know that I have to call the SetupGlobalThing() method before calling it?  What happens if I call IncrementGlobalThing() and DecrementGlobalThing() and MultiplyGlobalThing() in varying orders, depending on the function the user selects?

Instead, prefer stateless methods where you pass in all the stuff to be changed and used:  IncrementThing(Integer thing) doesn't rely on hidden setup steps.  It clearly does one thing: it increments the thing passed in.

It may help to think about it from a unit testing viewpoint.  If you were to write a unit test to prove a specific module of code works, would you need to pass in a real database connection (hard*), or would you be able to pass in a fake database reference that meets your testing needs easily?

The best way to test your logic is to unit test it.  The best way to test your class interfaces and method structure is to write unit tests that call them.  If the class is hard to test, it's likely due to dependencies upon external things (globals, singletons, databases, inappropriate member variables, etc.)

- The reason I called using a real database "hard" is that a unit test needs to be easy and fast to run.  It shouldn't rely on slow or breakable or complex external things.  Think about unit testing your software on the bus, with no network connection.  Think about how much work it is to create a dummy database: you have to add users, you have to have the right version of schema in it, it has to be installed, it has to be filled with the right kind of testing data, you need network connectivity to it, all those things can make your testing unreliable.  Instead, in a unit test you pass in a mock database, which simply returns values that exercise your code being tested.

Comment: If you saw the general code we have at present, you'll appreciate why unit testing is actually impossible for us. Most of the constructors in the legacy classes have a ton of parameters rather than the recommended 0 - 3 (Martin Fowler). I've personally ran one or two unit tests to learn about them but at present they're not used at all. I'm hoping our next architecture design will be far more layered, composed and testable but that's future-where I can have a shot at applying the stuff from all my books :). Right now, I'm in the middle of old style code that I'm refactoring.

Comment: The global db is for a content editor, internal use only, so it is convenience really. If I could safely instantiate it via Aspects (PostSharp) that would be handy but I think the suggestion of a resource string and instantiate at need is probably what I should do. Thank you!